# Accurate way to verify AWS EC2 limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use;

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
response = client.describe_account_attributes(AttributeNames=['max-instances'])
```

to obtain EC2 limits of a particular region. It returns '20' as max instance limit. But when I try to use "create_instance" api or launch instances manually via console it fails after 6 instances in one region and after 14 instances in another region.

I am not able to find accurate mechanism to verify account limits. Can someone help on this.

Comment: Were there any other Amazon EC2 instances running in those accounts at the time? The limit is on concurrently running instances. Also, what type of instances did you try to launch? There are different limits per instance type. The easiest way to view them is to click the `Limits` link in the Amazon EC2 management console.

Comment: Thanks John for the response. There were '5' t2.micro instances running and the limits page showed 20 for 't2.micro'.